# Climatological datasets

Tags: time-series, dataset, climate

What are some good repositories of climatological data? Is there a golden standard used in the community?

I need some datasets with gridded data with a reasonably good resolution, both temporal (monthly, at least) and spatial.

My goal is to perform a time series analysis using the information on temperature, cloud coverage, precipitation (other suggestions?)

Any information would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You might want to err, explore [KNMI Climate Explorer](https://climexp.knmi.nl/start.cgi).  It has projections from climate models, but it also has "reanalysis" data, which is gridded data that has been assimilated from station data using a climate/weather model.  I'm not sure if it has cloud coverage, but it certainly has temperature and precipitation.